# SVG's <text> elements have wrong height

Tags: javascript, svg, text

I want to know why there is such a big free space above and below the text?

I am using a custom font from Google Fonts.

pic:

[image: text with extra offset]

Unfortunately, this is screwing up my calculations.

Comment: Can you add some code, please?

Comment: That's probably because the bounding box of the `<text>` element takes into account space reserved for descenders, and also the cap height.

Comment: The height of the blue box is equal to the line height.